# морфемный разбор, словообразование

Tags: словообразование

Здравствуйте! Какой частью слова является буква -д- в слове увядший, частью корня или одним из двух суффиксов? И еще, объясните, пожалуйста,с точки зрения этимологии появление буквы д в этом слове. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Словари русского языка, а вернее, их составители допускают ошибку, когда приводят формы глагола *увянуть, увядать* (сов. и несов. виды), но абсолютно забывают вариант ***увясть***. Именно эта глагольная финаль СТ перешла в Д : увясть >> увядший (глагол и причастие одного вида, заметьте, совершенного!) Д вошло в состав корня, разумеется. Глагол ***увясть*** живет в языке до сих пор, он никуда не исчезал, разве что из словарей...

> Павел Мейлахс. Избранник (1996) // «Звезда», 2001
>   Непонятно, зачем он так долго стоял перед этой могилой, ... разглядывая эту надпись, ... цветы, принесенные к могиле, **не успевшие еще увясть.**

Итак : увясть (увянуть) - увядший (прош.вр., СВ); увядать - увядавший, увядающий (прош. и наст. вр., НСВ).

Comment: Существуют стандартные схемы образования причастий для глаголов на СТИ/СТЬ. Глаголы с основой на СТИ образуют причастия от основы настоящего (а не прошедшего) времени на Д/Т: забрести – забредет – забредший, отцвести – отцветет – отцветший: Для глаголов на СТЬ (красть, класть, сесть) используется суффикс ВШ: упасть – упал – упавший, присесть – присел – присевший.Тогда увясть - увял - увявший, но эта схема здесь не работает.

Comment: Выше вы приводили примеры  нести – нёс – нёсший, расти – росший, пасти – пасший, везти – вёзший, образование причастий в которых происходит по правилу: действительные причастия прошедшего времени образуются от основы прошедшего времени с помощью суффикса Ш для основ на согласную, а не потому, что что оканчиваются на СТИ.

Comment: Глаголы на ТИ следует отличать от глаголов на СТИ, это НЕМНОГО РАЗНЫЕ глаголы, и причастия от них образуются по разным схемам. Сравните: нести - нёс (С входит в корень) - несший, забрести - забрел   (С усекается) - забредет - забредший

Answer (score 2):

**Из словаря**: УВЯНУТЬ,  **увядший и увянувший**;  (нсв. вянуть, увядать).

В некоторых причастиях используется **нестандартная схема образования**:

увянуть (СВ) - увядать (НСВ) - увядает - увядший, образование от основы настоящего времени глагола несовершенного вида "увядать",

суффикс Ш, Д относится к основе, чередование СТ/Д (сравнить: напасть - нападать).

**Грамматическая справка** (образование действительных причастий прошедшего времени)

Действительные причастия прошедшего времени  образуются **от основы прошедшего времени:**

А)  с помощью **суффикса ВШ** для основ **на гласную**: писать - писал – писавший, отчаяться – отчаялся - отчаявшийся;

Б) с помощью **суффикса Ш** для основ **на согласную**:  нести – нёс – нёсший, расти – росший, пасти – пасший, везти – вёзший, сжечь – сжёгший, лечь – лёгший.

В  частных случаях для образования причастий используется **основа настоящего времени**: отцвести - отцветут – отцветший.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Основа у глагола увядать -увяда-, не получается увядший. Есть глагол увять, в котором корень -вя-, получается, -д- все-таки суффикс.

Comment: В русском языке нет суффикса Д, а чередование СТ/Д является регулярным.    Словарь говорит о том, что увядший - это форма глагола увянуть. Также в словаре нет глаголов вять и увять. Сложный глагол, вот и схема нестандартная, происходит усечение основы на гласную А. К примеру, обратите внимание на две схемы образования глаголов на СТЬ: пасть - падет - падший, пасть - пал - павший.

Answer (score 1):

> Какой частью слова является буква -д- в слове увядший, частью корня
>   или одним из двух суффиксов?

Частью **корня**.

======================================================

> И еще, объясните, пожалуйста, с точки зрения этимологии появление буквы
>   д в этом слове.

***ВЯД*** в этом слове -- исторический корень. Из  *"Корнеслова русского языка"* Фёдора Шимкевича (1842):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В словах ***ВЯДнуть*** (вянуть), ***уВЯДнуть*** (увянуть) "д" перед "н" со временем выпало (дн→н),  в причастии ***уВЯДший*** осталось.

Впоследствии слово ***увядший*** потеряло свою причастность, стало прилагательным. В современном русском языке такого причастия нет.  *"Русская грамматика"* о слове *увядший* пишет так (см. § [1584](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1576-1595.html)): *"прежнее прич. прош. увя'дший - теперь только прилагательное"*.

Так же это слово характеризует и Зализняк.

Comment: В одном из ответов в этой теме прозвучало: _"**суффикс**... **Д** относится к основе, **чередование СТ/Д** (сравнить: напасть - нападать)"._  К сожалению, никакого чередования СТ/Д  в цепочке _увяднуть -> увянуть -> увядать -> увядший_ я найти не сумел.

Comment: Зато вам повезло с ветчиной, которая образуется от глагола "вядить".  Вообще-то считается, что ветчина образована от слова ветхий - ветшина, сравнить: свежий - свежина, но у Фёдора Шимкевича (1842), видно, другое мнение.

Comment: _Vera: Вообще-то считается, что ветчина образована от слова ветхий._ === Те люди, которые придерживаются этой версии, всё-таки не отметают полностью и другие. 
 А уж как оно было на самом деле, пока одному Богу известно.

Comment: Да я к тому, что и  ВЯДнуть, взятое  из этого источника,  вызывает у меня большие сомнения.